# Tableau JS filter: Using javascript API, move filters from one dashboard to another

Tags: javascript, filter, tableau-api, embedding

I am using Javascript API to embed tableau reports in my website. I want the default Tableau behaviour of it saving the filters of one dashboard in a workbook, while moving to another dashboard in the similar workbook.

For example:

> If default date in a workbook is Jan-1 and I change it to Jan-2 in one
>   of the dashboards, it should reflect in other dashboards in the same
>   workbook. (In my embedded Tableau workbook!)

My code:

```
function initializeViz(url){
    var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
    var options = {
        width: placeholderDiv.offsetWidth,
        height: placeholderDiv.offsetHeight,
        hideTabs: true,
        hideToolbar: true,
        onFirstInteractive: function () {
            workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
            activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
        }
    };
    var x=url;
    if(viz!=null){
    viz.dispose();}
    viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
}
```

P.S.

This is closest thing I could find: [Saving and restoring current view state of a Tableau graph through javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33695684/saving-and-restoring-current-view-state-of-a-tableau-graph-through-javascript-ap)

I tried to find to find solution/documentation here: http://documents.tips/documents/javascript-api.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options here:

1. If the user is changing a filter in the dashboard you can make the filter apply to all worksheets using the same data source (does not require the JS API and is very simple to do).
   [image]
2. If you want to read the filters from the view and then apply them somewhere else you can use `Worksheet.getFiltersAsync()` which [returns a collection of Filter classes](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_concepts_filtering.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Option 1, it is already implemented, but it doesn't work when the dashboards are embedded in tableau. Regarding Option 2, it gives a Javascript Object with all filter values and only way I know to apply it to another sheet is to parse the Object and apply filters one by one to another worksheets, that's a lengthy painful process. So, this doesn't help me.